# Разместить часть компонента в другом компонетне?

Tags: reactjs, компоненты

Подскажите пожалуйста, как разместить часть одного компонента в другом компоненте?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

выноси в отдельную компоненту.

```
export const NewComponent = ({filter, setFilter}) => (
<> // Общий родительский тег (пустой узел)
<h1 className="sectionHeader">
Our 
<span className="sectionTitleText">Production</span>
</h1>
<ChoiseProductFilter filter={filter} setFilter={setFilter}/>
<a className="goCatalogLink" href="#">Go To Catalog</a>
</>
)
```

И внутри компоненты `Category` после `<AutoCarousel />`
вставь `<NewComponent filter={filter} setFilter={setFilter} />`

Comment: а как-нибудь композицией это нельзя сделать? примерно как тут, у меня просто не получается https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html